# Is it possible to render a different page when user is signed in? Rails 4 devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to render a different home page when a User logs in, but Devise keeps rendering the same page. Is it possible to change this? I know you can do it directly in the home page source code, but that seems long and inefficient. For example, I know how to check if a user is logged in, but how would I render a different view when they are logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an `after_sign_in_path` to take logged in users to a specific page directly after logging in, if that's what you're after.

ApplicationController:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  some_path
end
```

Devise will automatically respect this.

[More details](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

For a homepage that is different if you are logged in or not, you can either set your `root_url` action to redirect logged in users or you can change the link to the home page in the view.

1) Controller redirection (my preference)

```
SomeController
  def home_page
    if current_user
      redirect_to account_path
    end
  end
end
```

2) Or in views

```
<%= link_to 'Home', (current_user ? account_path : root_url) %>
```

Comment: Will this set that page as the home page? or will it just redirect it?

Comment: This will redirect a user directly after they sign in, not change the homepage. So to be clear, is what you want for the user to have a "home page" that is different if they are logged in or not?

Comment: Yes That is what I wanted.